# Does firebase use local storage to persist auth state by default?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase email login with my ionic app.

I haven't set up any auth state persistence in my entire app.

When I close (not minimize, really close it) and re-open the app, the user is still logged in (which is ok and my expected behaviour).

on important pages I just check if the user is authenticated and it all works fine:

```
if(firebase.auth().currentUser !== null){

  console.log('user is logged in!');

else{
  //redirect user to login
}
```

So I am just wondering, if firebase uses local storage to persist auth state on the background by default?

**what I am trying to achieve?**: let users sign in once and never log them out unless they log out by themselves or uninstall the app

**what I have right now in the app**?: currently it is working as expected, just want to confirm that firebase is keeping auth state on default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence):

> For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's
>   session even after the user closes the browser. This is convenient as
>   the user is not required to continuously sign-in every time the web
>   page is visited on the same device.

So, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: thank you, also found ionic + firebase based answer for confirmation: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-remember-logged-in-user-when-closing-and-opening-app/75907